# CSS Navigation bar full size

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

so I am running WordPress, with a premium theme.

I wish to change the navigation bar size, and so I added

```
li
{
float:left;
}
a
{
display:block;
width:60px;
}
```

When I add this, the navigation bar changes size, and becomes as I want to. HOWEVER, also the posttitles changes layout, and becomes really ugly.

I am looking for some input

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting li elements globally, it may be affecting more than just the nav area.  Try adding more specificity to your rule.

i.e. "`.nav li`" (.nav being whatever the class or id of your nav is) instead of just "li"

Answer (score 0):

sounds like float is affecting other elements. Using `clear:both` should fix this.

```
<ul>
 <li>....</li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

and .css

```
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: For thanks for the answers. It didn't work tho, its just exact like before.